# How to select JCheckBox by text in AssertJ Swing when there are multiple checkboxes in the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, assertj

The application has checkboxes text depending on the the selection of ComboBox in previous Step. I need to select one of the checkboxes in the JPanel using text. Is there a way to do it in AssertJ Swing

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the code that creates the checkboxes then give them distinct names:

```
JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox();
cb1.setName("CheckBox1");
JCheckBox cb2 = new JCheckBox();
cb2.setName("CheckBox2");
```

The name of a checkbox (of any component) is not displayed, but can be helpful while debugging the code and while testing the code.

To select the checkboxes with AssertJ Swing, you can then use the following code (with `frame` referencing the `FrameFixture`):

```
frame.checkbox("CheckBox1").check();
frame.checkbox("CheckBox2").check();
```